# File Path not Found for texture creation in openGL

Tags: java, opengl, png, textures, filepath

I am currently trying to create a textured polygon using JOGL, and I think I have everything set up.  However, when I try to load my png image into the TextureReader, it tells me that the file is not found.  The program and image are both located within the project titled Videos.

```
texture = genTexture(gl);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    TextureReader.Texture texture = null;
    try {
        texture = TextureReader.readTexture("Videos/boy_reaching_up_for_goalpost_stencil.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use an absolute path (like `/home/user/some/folders/Videos/boy_reaching_bla_bla.png`)?

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with OpenGL but with a wrong specified path...

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you.  I was under the impression that if the picture was in the project folder, the absolute path was unneccessary.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Indeed. But it was a "tool" to find out if there was a real issue or if something wrong with the path. You can use a relative path as well ;)